# File Watcher console application closes after one execution

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application that watches for directory, It runs only once, I need the application to keep running and watching the directory for files.

The code also check if the files are already, if it is then it moves it, it there is none it should wait and watch, but the wait and watch is not happening.

Here is the code

```
class Program
    {
        public static String stagepath = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\.NET Data Loader\stage\";
        public static String archivePath = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\.NET Data Loader\archive\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(stagepath);
            FileInfo[] file = dirinfo.GetFiles();
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                MoveFile(stagepath);
            }
            else
            {

                MonitorDirectory(stagepath);
            }


        }

        public static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = path;
           watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Changed += FileCreated;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


        }

        private static void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!FileIsReady(stagepath+e.Name)) return;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            MoveFile(stagepath);



        }

        private static  bool FileIsReady(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static void MoveFile(string path)
        {

            string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            var sort = from fn in fileNames
                       orderby new FileInfo(fn).Name ascending
                       orderby new FileInfo(fn).LastWriteTime ascending
                       select new FileInfo(fn).Name;
            foreach (string fi in sort)
            {

                System.IO.File.Move(stagepath +fi, archivePath+fi);
                Console.WriteLine($"File {fi} has been sucessfully moved ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course it does. Your Main() and the methods it calls have no looping in it, so it runs once and is done.

Comment: I completely understand that, but i am not sure how to effectively loop..

Comment: This egg has to go before the chicken.  *First* decide what the user should do to make your program stop running.  *Then* it becomes easy to decide what code you need.  For possible inspiration, consider [the Any Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any_key).

Comment: Well this application is going to be running in the background processing files as they arrive. The only way the application would stop, is if the service is stopped manually, otherwise consider this as an infinite loop, unless service stopped

Answer (score 1):

Put your code that moves files in a loop, like a while loop. Be sure to put a Thread.Sleep after each cycle.
[MSDN - Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hook up your events for the FileSystemWatcher just once upon initialize.

Probably, going to want a way to exit the loop, unless killing the process is sufficient.

---

**Update**

I revamped it so no loop was needed. You're going to have to modify this a bit to get it exactly how you want it, but at least now you have a working example. In the future use the Visual Studio/IDE debugger there was a number of things wrong with the original example.

Your issue specifically was that your file paths were jamming the path and the file name together so for example a file located C:\temp\foo.txt would become C:\tempfoo.txt. Then you were checking if the file could be opened before moving it, which it cannot because the malformed path doesn't exist. Additionally, the console just needs to be kept open, looping is not necessary. The event was still being triggered properly just the code to move files had a bug. You may want to remove the sleep from the FileCreatedInMonitoredDirectory event handler I don't think it is needed, but I left it in there because that's how it was originally.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string _monitoringPath = @"C:\temp";
        private static string _destinationPath = @"C:\dest";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MonitorDirectory(_monitoringPath);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = path;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Changed += FileCreatedInMonitoredDirectory;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private static void FileCreatedInMonitoredDirectory(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {         
            MoveFilesInDirectory(_monitoringPath);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        private static bool CanFileBeOpened(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                    return true;
            }
            catch (IOException ioEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Warning: File could not be opened, it will not be moved. {ioEx}" );
                return false;
            }
        }

        private static void MoveFilesInDirectory(string dirPath)
        {
            string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath);
            var sortedFileNames = from fn in fileNames
                                  orderby new FileInfo(fn).Name ascending
                                  orderby new FileInfo(fn).LastWriteTime ascending
                                  select new FileInfo(fn).Name;

            foreach (string fileName in sortedFileNames)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(_monitoringPath, fileName);

                if (!CanFileBeOpened(filePath))
                    continue;

                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                if (fileInfo.Length > 0)
                {
                    File.Move(Path.Combine(_monitoringPath, fileName), Path.Combine(_destinationPath, fileName));
                    Console.WriteLine($"File {fileName} has been moved successfully.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind giving me a example  on how do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just change your code as below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(stagepath);
        FileInfo[] file = dirinfo.GetFiles();
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            MoveFile(stagepath);
        }
        else
        {

            MonitorDirectory(stagepath);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

When you are using file watcher, another thread is made that it is live till your application is run. so you need just  keep your application run with any strategy.

Comment: Well it keep the window active, but when a new file comes in it doest execute anything

Comment: Use debugger and see what happens when you create a new file